# Bitbucket ssh pipeline fails - Missing or empty command string

Tags: ssh, yaml, bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I was trying to SSH to my server and pull the code and do some configuration stuff, each time code is pushed to master branch. I defined all of my repository variables used in this yaml file.
I also added ssh key, added host in the list of known hosts and fetched fingerprint.

This is my **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - name: "SSH Deploy to production web"
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.6
              variables:
                SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
                SERVER: $SSH_SERVER
                COMMAND: $SSH_COMMAND
                PORT: $SSH_PORT
```

The error I get is:

[image]

I checked my yml file using [bitbucket validator](https://bitbucket-pipelines.prod.public.atl-paas.net/validator) and everything seems to be OK.
I would appreciate any help since I just started using bitbucket pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

`name` isn't a property of `script`.

Refactor to be

```yaml
master:
  - step:
      name: "SSH Deploy to production web"
      script:
        - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.6
          variables:
            SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
            SERVER: $SSH_SERVER
            COMMAND: $SSH_COMMAND
            PORT: $SSH_PORT
```